# Flutter: Failed showing keyboard in TextFormField

Tags: flutter, textformfield

I have a **TextFormField** widget but I don't know why keyboard isn't working in it!!

When pressing on the widget it shows the keyboard then close it immediately, and prints this messages in console:

> D/InputConnectionAdaptor( 7900): The input method toggled cursor monitoring on

> W/OnBackInvokedCallback( 7900): OnBackInvokedCallback is not enabled for the application.

> Set 'android:enableOnBackInvokedCallback="true"' in the application manifest.

> D/InputConnectionAdaptor( 7900): The input method toggled cursor monitoring off

and when I add that line to the androidmanifest, it doesn't do any thing!!!

This is my code:

```
class SearchBox extends StatelessWidget {
  const SearchBox({
    super.key,
    required this.controller,
  });

  final TextEditingController controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: Dimensions.widthPercentage(context, 10),
          vertical: Dimensions.heightPercentage(context, 2)),
      child: Container(
        height: Dimensions.heightPercentage(context, 8),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: AppColors.whiteColor,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
            Dimensions.radius(context, 2.55),
          ),
        ),
        child: TextFormField(
          controller: controller,
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.none,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            hintText: 'What do you like to eat today?'.tr,
            hintStyle: TextStyle(
              fontSize: Dimensions.fontSize(context, 3.75),
              color: AppColors.hintSmallText,
              fontFamily: 'ReadexPro',
            ),
            border: InputBorder.none,
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              horizontal:
                  Dimensions.widthPercentage(context, 10),
              vertical:
                  Dimensions.heightPercentage(context, 3),
            ),
            suffixIcon: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  right: Dimensions.widthPercentage(
                      context, 3)), // Adjust as needed
              child: const Icon(
                Icons.search,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

***Update:*** here where I call this widget "SearchBox" in HomePage screen:

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> homeKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

    return Obx(
      () {
        final controller = Get.find<HomePageController>();

        return SafeArea(
          child: Material(
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              children: [
                Scaffold(
                  backgroundColor: AppColors.background,
                  key: homeKey,
                  body: ListView(
                    children: [
                      BigImage(
                        controller: controller.pageController,
                        length: controller.images.length,
                        listItem: controller.images,
                        hasText: false,
                        isHomePage: true,
                      ),
                      SearchBox(
                        controller: controller.searchController,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Visibility(
                  visible: !isDrawerOpen.value,
                  child: BNBWidget(
                    scaffoldKey: homeKey,
                    cartStatus: controller.items.isNotEmpty,
                    onHomeTap: () {},
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Couldn't reproduce. Can you [edit] your question to show how you are calling `SearchBox`?

Comment: @MendelG I have added an update, please see it

Comment: The onBackInvokeCallback is just a warning and can be ignored, it is not causing the problem... Have you tried debugging? Is the Homepage being rebuilt on keyboard opening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the solution.

Because I'm depending on Getx for StateManagement, so when use **TextFormField** I have to use **StatefullWidget** instead of **StatelessWidget.**

Answer (score 0):

Add dependencies in android/app/src/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation "androidx.activity:activity:1.6.1"
}
```

See the document on https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/custom-back/predictive-back-gesture?hl=en

Answer (score -1):

after changing the manifest file you should uninstall app and flutter clean, flutter  pub get and finally flutter run.